# поиск данных по связанной таблице

Tags: c#, mysql

через datagridview пытаюсь организовать поиск данных из связанных полей. запрос возвращает ID. я хочу получить значение вместе ID. как это можно организовать ? ниже выложил запрос поиска

```
 private void SearchTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchData = SearchTextbox.Text;
        con.Open();
    
        adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM sats WHERE name LIKE '%" + searchData + "%' OR surname LIKE '%" + searchData + "%' OR phone LIKE '%" + searchData + "%' OR login LIKE '%" + searchData + "%' OR dslam_id LIKE '" + searchData + "%' OR vdsl LIKE '%" + searchData + "%' OR port LIKE'%" + searchData + "%'", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        con.Close();
        DGVStil.Grid1style(dataGridView1);

    }
```

еще один момент, при поиске по столбцу phone как можно пропустит textbox-e ввод (777), а только остальные цифры.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
хотелось бы получить вот эти значения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот итоговый вид таким хочу видеть
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какое значение хотите получить вместо Id?

Comment: добрый день, выложил изображение со значениями

Comment: код запроса связки выглядит таким образом `SELECT sats.id, sats.name, sats.surname, sats.phone, sats.login, dslam.dslam, dslam.ip, sats.port, sum.name AS 'SATS', dslam.vdsl FROM sats JOIN dslam ON sats.dslam_id = dslam.id JOIN sum ON sats.sats_id = sum.id`

Comment: А что вы получаете из вашего запроса в строке `adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter...`?

Comment: если вы имеете в виду запрос поиска , то я загрузил изображение выше с результатом запроса.  если хотите видеть как хочу видеть общий результат запроса то , щас загружу изображение

Comment: Понятно, а в чем проблема поиска-то? Что выводится в датагридвью при поиске?

Comment: блин, выводится ID вместе значения, потому что храню ID вместе значения

Comment: Ну сделайте еще запросы по найденным Id а дальше результат в одну таблицу

Comment: вы имеете в виду под запросы ? я не понял вас . я хочу видеть результат таким  `SELECT sats.id, sats.name, sats.surname, sats.phone, sats.login, dslam.dslam, dslam.ip, sats.port, sum.name AS 'SATS', dslam.vdsl FROM sats JOIN dslam ON sats.dslam_id = dslam.id JOIN sum ON sats.sats_id = sum.id`  , как туда пристроит оператор LIKE ?

Comment: `WHERE параметр_нейм LIKE какоето_значение`

Comment: блин, спасибо ! я столько мучался , оказывается ошибка самом синтактиксе. тоесть где WHERE параметр_нейм указал только название поле. а нужно было еще дописать 'таблица.поле', еще один момент, как настроит поиск, чтобы пропустит значение в скобках ? (777) 65-467-453

Comment: Если у вас записи ВСЕГДА идут в формате `(xxx) xx-xxx-xxx`, то можете получить значение с помощью регулярки: `Regex.Match(number, @"([\d]{2}-[\d]{3}-\d{3})");` Если не хотите с регулярками,то можно просто при поиске удалять первые 3-4 символа `number.Remove(0,3)`

Comment: понял, спасибо вам большое !